# VBA Save As special character error

Tags: vba, excel

This code below was running perfect.
For internal report tracking purposes I've appended "[1944] " to the front of the file name.
It's now kicking back "Run-time error '1004'" at me.

**Error 1004 Checklist**

- Folder exists
- File is not read-only
- Len(file path) < 218

Last section references not using the following characters
< > ? [ ] : | or *

But if I go to the folder location I can rename it using [ ] no problem.
I can even title a file with this and launch it using VBA
So why can't I save a file with it in.

Anyone got a work around for me?

Many thanks!

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    strfilepath & "[1944] TSA34_MI_" & strdt & ".xlsb" _
    , FileFormat:=xlExcel12, Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", _
    ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=False
```

Comment: I'd be careful with that, might be less a problem for the workbook's name, but I did that once for the sheet's name and I could never open back my workbook and lost all the work I already had done on that file...

Comment: That's not an issue for me really. This is part of a much bigger macro that takes last weeks report. updates it and does a saves as with the new date. So if it crashes i'll just reproduce the same doc

Comment: I believe that the reason the code won't write the file is an attempt at cross-compatibility with `office-mac-vba`.

Comment: mac hasn't been associated with this file at all???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only workaround I can think of is renaming the file once it is closed.

To do this you can use the `Name` statement. See [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266171(v=vs.60).aspx).

```
Name "C:\Users\lturner\Documents\myWorkbook.xlsb" As "C:\Users\lturner\Documents\[1]myWorkbook.xlsb"
```

Aside from this, I don't think it's possible to save the workbook with square brackets in the name.

Comment: It may not be pretty but it works. Set it to Save with the new date, Close, Name, Reopen. Many thanks @Iturner

Comment: Yeah, very inconvenient.. but glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

Square brackets are legal characters for windows file names, but are treated specially by Excel, and hence VBA.

To see why, open two workbooks and in the first pick a cell and enter the formula "=SUM(", then click a cell in the second workbook.  Your formula will now look something like this "=SUM([Workbook2]Sheet1!A1)". Square brackets are used as workbook name delimiters.

Comment: Ohhh I see the logic. Shouldn't affect me here but will need to remember going forward. Thanks @Carl Fried Rice Gauss

Comment: Also, watch out for single quotes.  These are also legal in windows, but are used in Excel when workbook or worksheet names have spaces in them.  (ex. ='[My Book Name.xlsx]My Sheet Name'!A1)  I suggest creating a class that can do regex tests against strings to test for valid workbook names, valid worksheet names, and valid windows file names.