# Converting xls files to csv where the filename includes [ ]

Tags: excel, vba

XLS files need converting to CSV (with all formatting removed), so they can be read via a VBA macro. Unfortunately, the xls filenames include [ ] so when i try to save them within vba, it fails with a  run-time error '1004' standard error "Make sure the file name does not contain ...[ ]
If i save the xls file manually (file-save as csv), it says the formatting will be lost but it saves the file. Is there a way i can get my VBA to do the same and effectively ignore the Run-Time error '1004' that gets shown?

i've tried a Replace to save the file to a temporary filename.
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Replace(xSPath & "\" & "TEMP_file_only.csv", ".xls", ".csv", vbTextCompare)

I then opened the temp file and used Name to rename it to CSV
     Name Tempfilename As OldFileAsCSV

Unfortunately, this preserves the xls formatting so the csv file isn't any good for the macro. It doesn't remove the formatting.

If i try to save the xls as a csv, i get the run-time error because there are [ ] in the filename, which are unfortuantely needed.

```
  ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=xCSVFile, FileFormat:=xlCSVMSDOS, Local:=True
```

I hoped Application.DisplayAlerts = false would ignore the 1004 error but because the filename contains [ ]  i guess it's a valid failure. however, if i save the file manually to csv it works and removes the formatting. Is there anyway in vba to save an xls to csv with [ ] in the filename?
Many thanks in advance

Comment: Why not save it without, and then rename the file (use the `Name` instruction)

Comment: It's discussed here too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31559498/vba-save-as-special-character-error

Comment: Hello I found the link mentioned whereby the workaround was to save the file as a temporary name.csv and then rename it back to the original name with the brackets and whilst this worked in terms of saving the file name with brackets, it didn't save the data as text (csv). Perhaps I did that step wrong? I tried the following:-

Comment: Sorry, it cut off some text in the last comment.

Comment: I tried     ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Replace(xSPath & "\" & "TEMP_file_only.csv", ".xls", ".csv", vbTextCompare)
   ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=xCSVFile, FileFormat:=xlCSVMSDOS
but the saving to temporary file hasn't saved the file with no formatting (text). The name statement has worked though and the brackets are there! How do i remove the xls formatting and just save as text in the Replace statement? thanks v much

Comment: Got this to work by doing the following:- Saving the file with [ ] in the name to a temporary file, with no brackets, in CSV MSDOS format
 ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=xSPath & "\" & "TEMP_file_only.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSVMSDOS. 
Then using Name to rename the file to the original file name with [ ] in the name. 
Tempfilename = xSPath & "\" & "TEMP_file_only.csv"
OldFileAsCSV = xcsvfileonly & "csv"  
Name Tempfilename As OldFileAsCSV
Thanks very much